# How to decompose my program into multiple methods?

Tags: java, methods, refactoring

How would I decompose this java program into multiple methods?
It first stores a string as input, then loops through it to extract all of the numbers into an array list. Then it prints all of these numbers along with their sum and product.

```
public class Assignment1 {
public static void main(String[] args){

    // Creates scanner for storing input string
    Scanner numScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    System.out.println("Enter a string of numbers to compute their sum and product:");
    System.out.println("(Enter '.' to terminate program)");
    input = numScanner.nextLine();


    // Terminates the program if there is no input
    if (input.length() == 0){
                System.out.println("Invalid input: Not enough characters");
                System.exit(-1);
    }


    // Terminates the program if the first character is '.'
    if (input.charAt(0) == '.'){
        System.out.println("Thank you for using numberScanner!");
        System.exit(-1);
    }


    // Defines all of the variables used in the loops
    int index = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int product = 1; 
    Integer start = null;
    int end = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();


    // Loop that extracts all numbers from the string and computes their sum and product
            while (index < input.length()){
                if (input.charAt(index) >= 'A' && input.charAt(index) <= 'Z' && start == null){
                    index++;
                }else if (input.charAt(index) >= '1' && input.charAt(index) <= '9' && start == null){
                    start = index;
                    index++;
                }else if (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(index))){
                    index++;
                }else{
                        end = index;
                        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(input.substring(start,end)));
                        sum += Integer.parseInt(input.substring(start,end));
                        product *= Integer.parseInt(input.substring(start,end));
                        index++;
                        start = null;
                }   
            }


            // For the last number, the end is greater than the length of the string
            // This prints the last number without using the end
            if (index == input.length()){
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(input.substring(start)));
            sum += Integer.parseInt(input.substring(start));
            product *= Integer.parseInt(input.substring(start));
            index++;
            }


        // Prints the Numbers, Sum and Product beside each other
        System.out.print("Numbers: ");
        for (Object a : numbers) {
            System.out.print(a.toString() + " ");
            }
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum + " Product: " + product);
}
```

}

I just don't know how to split the single method into multiple methods

Comment: I think you're making this far more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: A method should do, where possible, a single job.  For example, you could write a `prompt` method, that took a `String` "prompt" and prompted the user for input, returning a value...

Comment: this belongs on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) not here.

Comment: The above code looks perfectly fine as one method -- it's not too big and doesn't appear to have any repeated sections, save for that small "last number" section.  Any "methodizing" you do would be more for show than for need.

Comment: I know its harder than it should be. I was restricted to only 5 functions

Answer (score 1):

I think having the I/O in the `main` method is OK here. What I would move out is the construction of the `numbers` list. You can have a method `getNumbers` that accepts a string and returns a list of the digits in that string. For instance:

```
private static List<Integer> getNumbers(String str) {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isDigit(c))
            numbers.add(c - '0');
    }

    return numbers;
}
```

Now it should be trivial to loop over the list returned by `getNumbers()` and to compute the sum/product of the elements:

```
List<Integer> numbers = getNumbers(input);

System.out.println(numbers);

int sum = 0;
int product = 1;

for (int i : numbers) {
    sum += i;
    product *= i;
}

System.out.printf("Sum: %d Product: %d%n", sum, product);
```